# Does anyone create open source auto driving car projects

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone create open source auto driving car projects， we can build a small car for delivery using auto driving technology，because our small car low weight and low speed, so I think is safe for people。

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31462/does-anyone-create-open-source-auto-driving-car-projects/) by [flowskyac](https://answers.ros.org/users/2141/flowskyac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-04-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[We have one](http://ros.org/wiki/utexas-art-ros-pkg), a collaboration between the University of Texas at Austin and Austin Robot Technology.

Recently, an [Ackermann steering interest group](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Ackermann%20Group) formed. It has begun defining some shared interfaces.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3